# Can we define a constructor in Vb.Net with a 'Friend' modifier?

Tags: vb.net

Can we define a constructor with 'Friend' modifier?

```
     Friend Class Reader

       Friend Sub New()
       End Sub

     End Class
```

Thanks!

Comment: You wouldn't have had to ask if you had simply tried to compile your own code example. Sorry, but -1 from me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, no problem.  It is superfluous since the Friend accessor on the class already puts the constructor out of reach.  The VB.NET compiler doesn't mind though, nor does the C# compiler for that matter.  There is no inconsistency.